# Save input value in a cvs file, adding a row at every submission, in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to build a shiny app similar where after having select the input data i can click on a "submit" botton that automatically upload a cvs file adding a row with the new data.
I see that the structure should be similar to a survey one, this is my code, it gives the following error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3716
Warning: Error in <-: invalid type/length (closure/0) in vector allocation
Stack trace (innermost first):
42: server [/Users/cleliagasparri/app2/app.R#47]
 1: runApp
Error in Data[nrow(Data) + 1, ] <- reactive(if (input$Action == 1) { : 
invalid type/length (closure/0) in vector allocation
```

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets)
library(DT)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
textInput("nome", "Nome"),

textInput("cognome", "Cognome"),

textInput("email", "Email"),

 radioButtons("gioiello", label = "Gioiello", choices = c("Orecchini" = 1, "Collana" = 2)
  ),

 conditionalPanel(condition = "input.gioiello == 1",
 selectInput(inputId = "modello",                
          label = "Modello",                                
          choices = c("Serpenti" = 1, "Foglie" = 2, "Edere" = 3,              # Responses
                          "Neither Agree nor Disagree" = 4, "Agree   Somewhat" = 5, "Agree" = 6,
                          "Agree Strongly" = 7)            
  )), 
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.gioiello == 2",
               selectInput(inputId = "modello",                    #      What we are calling the object
                               label = "Modello",                                    # Label
                           choices = c("Serpenti" = 1, "Foglie" = 2, "Edere" = 3,       # Responses
                                       "Neither Agree nor Disagree" = 4, "Agree Somewhat" = 5, "Agree" = 6,
                                       "Agree Strongly" = 7)            
               )),
 radioButtons("materiale", label = "Materiale", choices = c("Oro",     "Argento", "Bronzo rosa", "Bronzo giallo", "Rame")
           ),

  actionButton("Action", "Submit"), tags$hr()


 )

library(shiny)
library("DT")                                                                                               

server <- function(input, output){
Results <- reactive(c(nome, cognome, email, gioiello, modello,     materiale, Sys.Date()))  

Data[nrow(Data) +1,] <- reactive(  if(input$Action == 1) {Results()})       #  Put data into next row of the "Data" when the action button is pressed
  write.csv(Data, file = "/Users/cleliagasparri/app2/Data.csv")                #  Download new Data to replace Data.csv file in the shiny folder


#####     Function 1, Create a data download option ####

 output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(            # Create the download file name
   filename = function() {
    paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
 },
 content = function(file) {
   write.csv(Data, file)                     # put Data() into the download file
 })                          

}                                                                                  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample data? Also the library should not be inside `""`. It should be `library(DT)` instead of `library("DT")`

Comment: Thank you! I want to use this app to insert data about jewels selling so after having insert the piece sold I click the "submit" button that add a row with the selling data in a csv file. A row should be populated in this way: name, surname, email, jewel type (earring, necklace, bracelet..), model (different for each type), material (gold, silver, bronze), price, sysdate

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the best way to do it but it does the work.

I have added one more button for download so it works with the download handler. To make what I am doing more clear I have added a table output. The submit button now appends the row to the table which is internally saved as a data frame. To save the file download button can be used.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("nome", "Nome"),

  textInput("cognome", "Cognome"),

  textInput("email", "Email"),

  radioButtons("gioiello", label = "Gioiello", choices = c("Orecchini" = 1, "Collana" = 2)
  ),

  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.gioiello == 1",
                   selectInput(inputId = "modello",                
                               label = "Modello",                                
                               choices = c("Serpenti" = 1, "Foglie" = 2, "Edere" = 3,              # Responses
                                           "Neither Agree nor Disagree" = 4, "Agree   Somewhat" = 5, "Agree" = 6,
                                           "Agree Strongly" = 7)            
                   )), 
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.gioiello == 2",
                   selectInput(inputId = "modello",                    #      What we are calling the object
                               label = "Modello",                                    # Label
                               choices = c("Serpenti" = 1, "Foglie" = 2, "Edere" = 3,       # Responses
                                           "Neither Agree nor Disagree" = 4, "Agree Somewhat" = 5, "Agree" = 6,
                                           "Agree Strongly" = 7)            
                   )),
  radioButtons("materiale", label = "Materiale", choices = c("Oro",     "Argento", "Bronzo rosa", "Bronzo giallo", "Rame")
  ),
  #Table showing what is there in the data frame
  tableOutput("table"),
  #Button which appends row to the existing dataframe
  actionButton("Action", "Submit"),

  #Button to save the file
  downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')


)

library(shiny)


server <- function(input, output){
  #Global variable to save the data
  Data <- data.frame()

  Results <- reactive(data.frame(input$nome, input$cognome, input$email, input$gioiello, input$modello,   input$materiale, Sys.Date()))  

  #To append the row and display in the table when the submit button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$Action,{
    #Append the row in the dataframe
    Data <<- rbind(Data,Results()) 
    #Display the output in the table
    output$table <- renderTable(Data)
  })



  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

# Create the download file name
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(Data, file)                     # put Data() into the download file
    })                          

}                                                                                  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! it works! Can I ask you how can I change the download path to save the cvs in another directory?

Comment: You can always choose the path from the file dialog that appears. Do you mean you want to save the file in a default file without a file dialog appearing?

Comment: If I understand well everytime the dataframe is downloaded a csv is created with the row submitted in the ongoing session. If I downloaded 2 csv in 2 different days, both with the same file name, the first will be overwritten; is it correct? thank you!

Comment: In the code above, currently whatever rows you see in the table output is  will be saved in the file when you click the download button. Also, if you save the file with the same file name the previous file will be overwritten. If you don't want this to happen then one workaround would be that you append the data to a file that is already present.

Comment: @SBista what if i want to have a different filename everytime i download the data. Is there some function to ask the user for the filename

Comment: @rahul yadav. You can have a `textInput` from which you can take a file name

Comment: That works fine, but i was hoping for the name choice option to pop up after the download button has been pressed.